# C++ Libraries ecosystem using CMake and Ryppl

Tags: c++, cmake

I am interested in building a cross-platform C++ Library and distributing it in source form.  I want the consumers of this library to be able to acquire it, build it and consume it inside their software very easily on whatever platform they are working on and for whatever platform they are targeting.  At the same time while building my library, I also want to be able to consume other popular OSS libraries through a similar mechanism.

I see that [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) and [Ryppl](http://ryppl.org/) were created with these intentions in mind and to some extent they do solve some of these problems, especially the build problem.  But I don't quite know how exactly to go about achieving the above mentioned goals.  Is it OK to settle on CMake as the build solution?  How do I solve the library acquisition and distribution problem?  Simply host the sources somewhere and let people discover, download and build them?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: Take a look at [ExternalProject_Add](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html?highlight=externalproject_add) command. This will help you to build and install third party dependencies (even if it's not a cmake projects). If you're ready to experiment you can test [this](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter) project I've made :)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing there is no accepted solution that handles everything you want.  CMake gives you cross-platform builds and git (with submodules) gives you a way to manage *source*-level dependencies if all other projects are using CMake.  But, in practice, many common dependencies you project wil need don't use CMake, or even Git.

Ryppl is meant to solve this, but progress is slow because the challenge is such a hard one.

Arguably, the most successful solution so far is to write header-only libraries.  This is common practice and means your users just include your files, and their build system of choice takes care of everthing.  There are no binary dependencies to manage.

Comment: @ruslo Header-only makes builds a bit slower of course but it's not a big problem.  Most Boost libraries are header-only, and they do ok.  Modern computers are fast.  In fact, in C++ you **have** to write much of your code in headers because you can't link against a separately-compiled template.

Answer (score 0):

TheHouse's answer is still essentially true. Also there don't seem to have been any updates to ryppl itself for a while (3 years) and the ryppl.org domain has expired.

There are some new projects aiming to solve the packaging issue. 
Both [build2](https://build2.org/) and [wrap](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/wiki/Wrap%20dependency%20system%20manual) from mesonbuild have that goal in mind.

A [proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0235r0.pdf) was made recently to add packages to the c++ standard which may open up the debate ([reddit discussion here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/474vsf/a_packaging_system_for_c_proposal/)).

Wrap looks promising as meson's author has learned from cmake. 
There is a good video when its author discussing this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTJtKtQ8R5k).
build2 seems more oblivious (and therefore condemned to reinvent). However both suffer from trying to solve the external project dependencies issue simultaneously with providing a complete build system.
[conan.io](http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/) is another recent attempt which doesn't try to provide the build system as well. Time will tell if any of these gain any traction.

The accepted standard for packaging C and C++ projects on Unix was always a source tarball + a configure script (autotools) + make.
cmake is now beginning to replace autotools as your first choice.
It is able create RPMs and tarballs for distribution purposes.

Its also worth considering the package managers built into the various flavours of Linux. The easiest to build and install projects are those where most of the dependencies can be pulled in via *yum* or *apt*. This won't help you on windows of course. While there is a high barrier to entry getting your own projects added to the main Linux repositories (e.g. RedHat, Debian) there is nothing to stop you adding your maintaining your own satellite repo.
The difference between that and just hosting your project on github or similar is you can provide pre-built binaries for a number of popular systems.

You might also consider that configure times checks (e.g. from cmake *findLibrary()*) and your own documentation will tell people what needs to be installed as a prerequisite and providing you don't make it too onerous that might be enough.